# Apply a function to multiple columns in dataframe and store result in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an input csv file something like below

[image]

and this is the output I want

[image]

using a function to calculate the result

```
def result(a,b):
    return a+b
```

How to apply this function to the dataframe to get the desired result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi in order to perform addition or any mathematical operation, in most of the case the type should be the same for both columns:
Assuming that you have same type of columns as int.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1':[5,6,0,0,0],'col2':[10,20,30,40,50]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for ind, item in enumerate(df['col1']):
   if item != 0:
    df['col'+str(ind+3)] = df.apply(lambda row : result(item, row['col2']), axis=1)
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the numeric values of one column, and assign a new column by simple addition.

```
>>> for (i, v) in enumerate(df['a'].dropna()):
...     df[f'col{i}']=v + df['b']
...
>>> df
     a   b  col0  col1
0  5.0  10  15.0  16.0
1  6.0  20  25.0  26.0
2  NaN  30  35.0  36.0
>>>
```

- the `dropna` - to avoid none values.
- when adding a series and a scalar, like `v + df['b']` the result will be addition of that scalar to every entry of the series.